# Putting the end result of a command into a variable

Tags: macos, bash, osx-yosemite

I am having some difficulties making variables behave the way I want them to...

I am trying to put the number that is the result of a string of piped commands into a variable so that I can manipulate that number later.

My first string looks like this:
`DiskSizeDecimal=$(diskutil list | grep 'Automation' | awk '{print $4}')`

I then input that new variable into this string:
`DiskSize=$(awk 'BEGIN { rounded = sprintf("%.0f", ‘$DiskSizeDecimal’); print rounded }’)`

I dont end up getting the result I need for $DiskSize because the string still seems to interpret $DiskSizeDecimal as a string of commands and not the number that it outputs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you! :)

Athena Harting

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in single command:

```
DiskSize=$(diskutil list | awk '/Automation/{printf "%.0f", $4}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. That helped me simplify my code a bit but i still encounter this issue later on in my code when I try to use $DiskSize in this line `FreeSpace=((('$DiskSize'-40)*1024))`

Comment: What is value of `$DiskSize`. Your last command should be: `FreeSpace=$(( ($DiskSize-40) * 1024 ))`

Comment: The value of $DiskSize will always be different depending on the system that the script is running on, even using your spaced out string, I still get the error `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "????-40) * 1024 ")`

Comment: I know `DiskSize` will be different but what is an **example value** of `$DiskSize`? Use `printf "<%s>\n" "$DiskSize"` to print it.

Comment: Then `DiskSize=249 && echo $(( (DiskSize-40) * 1024 ))` is giving me output as: `214016`. Can you also test it?

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed! I ended up using $(echo $DiskSize) in the commands that I needed to use the variable in which allowed the number to be seen rather than the command. Thank you anbhava for all of your help! :D